# Where can I find the archival records of a US "Committee on Armed Services Hearings" held in 1963?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, reference-request

This is the full citation:

> U.S., Congress, House, Committee on Armed Services, Hearings on the Military Posture, 88th Cong., 1st sess., 30 January 1963

I looked for it here - [Congressional Hearings](https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/chrg/88) - but couldn't find it. Any idea where I can read it? Perhaps it is not declassified fully for the public, and only available to academics?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015071164118&view=1up&seq=9)?

Comment: @C.F.G - That is a directory of those who took part in the 88th Congress. I am looking for the text of "Hearings on the Military Posture" by the Committee on Armed Services during the 88th Congress. Thanks for pointing to that resource though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote you're looking for was from "Study of U.S. and NATO Nuclear Weapons Arrangements" (1961-02-11, [PDF](https://declassification-engine-ddo.s3.amazonaws.com/CK2349601635-jcoae-nato-nuclear-arrangements-1961.pdf), p. 30):

> In the event of hostilities, assuming NATO will not strike the first blow, the USSR with its ballistic missile capabilities logically could be expected to take out these bases on the first attack, which undoubtedly would be a surprise attack.

---

Notes:

1. Your quote is from Bernstein ([1980](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2149587?seq=3)), who incorrectly adds the word "that" after "assuming" and changes the word "capabilities" to "capability".
2. The above was quoted by Robert McNamara in Hearings on Military Posture, [1963-01-30, p. 279](https://books.google.com/books?id=OfLYSCSLZdQC&pg=PA279) (this is correctly cited by Bernstein).
3. The above was again quoted by McNamara on [1963-02-19](https://books.google.com/books?id=h9AQAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA7).

Answer (score 3):

**[Full text of "Congressional Record January 9-30, 1963: Vol 109"](https://archive.org/stream/sim_congressional-record-proceedings-and-debates_january-9-30-1963_109/sim_congressional-record-proceedings-and-debates_january-9-30-1963_109_djvu.txt)**

I searched on "January 30, 1963",  or "Military Posture"

Comment: Thanks JMS. However, I am unable to find this quote in it - *"In the event of hostilities, assuming that NATO will not strike the first blow," a then-secret congressional report warned, "the USSR with its ballistic missile capability logically could be expected to take out these bases on the first attack, which undoubtedly would be a surprise attack."* (This is text that has the citation in question)

Comment: It is supposed to be on Page 277, but as you can see - https://archive.org/details/sim_congressional-record-proceedings-and-debates_january-9-30-1963_109/page/276/mode/2up - there's no mention of that topic at all in that page.

Comment: I just don't have enough details on what you're looking for to help.   I did find this paper but don't know if it's helpful.   **[Why Did the Eisenhower Administration Decide To Deploy Jupiter Missiles in Turkey: a Case Study in Nuclearization of Nato 
Strategy](https://ir.library.illinoisstate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2182&context=etd)**

Comment: I am just trying to verify a reference and learn more. This paper - https://psi329.cankaya.edu.tr/uploads/files/Bernstein%2C%20Cuban%20Missile%20Crisis--Trading%20the%20Jupiters%20in%20Turkey.pdf (PDF) - includes the above quote (on page number 99) and says it is from the above hearing that i have cited in the question.

Comment: @sfxedit People make erroneous citations all the time. It could also be that a paraphrase was misattributed as a quotation, or that the author had several references and used the wrong one.